# rvm is not avilable used by another user

Tags: linux, bash

I have rvm installed on my production server.

it's installed under the user `jenkins`.

when I ssh into the server and switch to jenkins

```
sudo su jenkins
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 2.1.8
```

when I run it from the startup script as a `root` user like so:

```
COMMANDS_TO_EXECUTE="
 source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm;
 rvm use 2.1.8;     
 "


echo "$COMMANDS_TO_EXECUTE" > /apps/script_to_execute.sh
sudo chmod +x /apps/script_to_execute.sh
su -s /apps/script_to_execute.sh - jenkins
```

getting 
rvm command not found

Comment: `root` probably does not have `rvm` included into his `$PATH`. You can use an absolute path to the command to easily avoid this.

Comment: The shell expands the `~` character to different paths when run by different users.